# False roof frame in ceiling

Tags: framing, attic

Have never figured out what this is. There is basically a false roof frame in the attic. The peak is the opposite direction of the actual roof. As far as I know there hasn't been any major remodeling to this house, definitely not something of the scale of adding a completely new roof. Can anyone tell me what the purpose of this is, or if it was just likely built accidentally and left in place? The area with plywood is over the kitchen as well, so possibly someone was planning on vaulting the kitchen ceiling?

[image]

Comment: That looks like an attempt to keep the ceiling joists aligned and forces distributed despite some force pulling downward on the center or pushing up on the ends. Are there any unusual loads in this area of the building? Is there a great room or other unusually long stretch of unsupported ceiling? Huge chandelier?

Comment: Not really any load under this section at all. It is about 4 - 5 ft over the garage which is a fairly lengthy distance from the wall to the garage door, but the only weight on the entire garage ceiling is the opener and the rails which are near the side walls. Definitely not much weight in the center and nothing within about 8ft of the actual peak in the photo.

Comment: The kitchen mention made me wonder if it was providing support for ceiling-hung kitchen cabinets. But now the location seems less clear.

Comment: Garage... Maybe someone was considering putting in a hoist. ... Ugly thought: Check the condition of the main beam above this. (House near me both had a cracked main beam and was off its foundation. No contractor's insurance would let them go near it since work on one might cause catastrophic failure of the other. Owner wound up demolishing and rebuilding.)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a "roof frame"; it's a truss. Its purpose is to keep the beam below it straight.